# Visual Studio: auto completes are no longer showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My auto completes are no longer showing up.  So, when I type a method or try to create a class and type "suchAndSuch.SoAndSo," the list of options is no longer showing up.  This is problematic because I am working with a lot of different libraries, most of which are new to me.

How do I get this feature turned back on?

Comment: have you tried clicking CTRL + SPACE?

Comment: Ok, that works.  Is there a way to make it automatic again?

Comment: You want to enable your IntelliSense.. In case you deactivated it somehow... you can enable it in the Visual Studio settings. Just browse to the Editor settings, then to the subgroup C/C++ (or whatever you are using) and activate it again...

Comment: But if you want my honest opinion... Use Visual Assist X.. I use it and really helps with coding and cuts down the time once you've figured out how to use it effectively.

Comment: And sometimes you just have to restart Visual Studio, if everything looks as it should but doesn't work as it should. :-/ :-)

Comment: @kamal But Visual Assist X isn't a free software I think...

Comment: Nope it is not free.. But totally worth every penny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: <kbd>EDIT</kbd> -> <kbd>Intellisense</kbd> -> <kbd>List Members</kbd>

And Check <kbd>TOOLS</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>TextEditor</kbd> -> `[your language]` -> <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Auto list members</kbd>